# Meteor: Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: performance, meteor

How to "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" in Meteor?

[image]

Comment: have you tried fast-render?
https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-fast-render.html

Comment: Fast-render is not the solution for this problem. It only speed up rendering of the page, but rendering will have to wait for downloading all javascript files and in case of meteor it is ~1MB (or more if your application is complex)

Comment: Great question! You could probably use a combination of [`WebApp`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) and [`Server-Side Rendering`](https://meteorhacks.com/server-side-rendering). I'm working on a solution, not sure if it's possible though. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I'm working on a solution [here](https://github.com/Kriegslustig/Meteor-without-blocking-the-rendering-process/blob/master/README.md). I created an example that pretty much works. But there's still a problem with `HCR` also it's a super ugly hack. So it's pretty useless. I'm still working on it tough. I might be able to find a good solution tomorrow. I'm looking at a lot of code in the Meteor core (which I haven't done before) so it's very time intensive.

Comment: I found, what I think is an ok solution... But I still have a dependency resolution issue to solve. It seems, that the the order in which meteor is listing the dependencies in the `manifest` is somehow wrong. Anyway, I'm still working on it. Just wanted to keep you updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Truth<sup>TM</sup>

After implementing a working solution for this problem, I'd say that the *right*<sup>TM</sup> answer to your question is: "No, that's just what you get for using such a complex javascript framework."

But it's still a fact that loading meteor can take over a minute, on slow networks. It is huge. That makes for an awful UX. So I think it would improve a meteor app overall to have something like a loading screen.

I'm writing a package [`kriegslustig:altboiler`](https://github.com/Kriegslustig/meteor-altboiler) *(I'll update this as soon as I do the first "major" release)*.

### Solution

I documented the solution that I'm using in `altboiler` [in this repo](https://github.com/Kriegslustig/Meteor-without-blocking-the-rendering-process#the-push-and-shove-approach). It got pretty long, so here's a summary:

- Use `WebApp.connectHandlers`
- Loop through `WebApp.clientPrograms[WebApp.defaultArch].manifest`
- Get all the URLs inside via AJAX
- Buffer and then compile them into one single `script` tag
- Insert that `script` tag into the `head`
- And then finally self destruct the loader script

That way you won't get that error on Google Pagespeed.

#### Potential

You could serve a loading screen first or you could also render the whole site without the parts that need a connection to the server.

### Performance

I expected this to load Meteor a lot slower, but in my initial test Meteor actually loaded faster. My test wasn't exactly scientific though. I simply loaded it in the Chrome emulator and throttled the connection to `50kbps`. Also, I did this on a dev instance, so it was uncompressed. The results are still somewhat relevant though:

Without `altboiler`: **1.7min**
With `altboiler`: **2.8min**

The ajax requests only perform better when there are a lot of requests made. So presumably the impact on a bundled instance could range from slightly worse to slightly better.

### Downsides

It might intervene with the [`spiderable`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spiderable) package, but I don't think so. I'll test it when I've written some tests for the package.

Comment: Thanks for this package. So if I use it I can expect the site to load slower? But it gives better user experience? Since with loads at 2.8min and without 1.7min

Comment: And I wonder why not use the fastrender package for example instead of this?

Comment: @nilsi that of course shouldn't happen. I probably could do some opimizations, I'll try it. Fastrender does something different. It sends *data* from collections along with the initial response.